# Could not verify the SSL certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, openssl, rubygems

My environment is WSL Ubuntu 16.04, Ruby 1.8.7 (2017-12-15 patchlevel 377) [x86_64-linux], Rails 2.3.10, openssl 1.0.2t. All of a sudden, starting yesterday, I can't bundle install. I've been using this system for over a year with no problems. When I run bundle install I get this error:

```
        Resolving dependencies.......
    Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/nokogiri-1.10.10.gemspec.rz.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA
certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html. To connect
without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
```

I've tried changing to http but it doesn't help. I've updated the ca cert using

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

but that didn't help. I deleted the Gemfile.lock as recommended by one article but still no help.

Any ideas? I've tried pretty much everything I've read about with no success. BTW, the link in the error message says the error won't occur after Ubuntu 12.04 so that's no help.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Have you tried `gem update --system` this has been shown to resolve similar issues in the past

Comment: Problem might be some antivirus on the windows system. Some are doing SSL interception, i.e. they are a man in the middle.

Comment: @engineersmnky. I use slimgems and it is the newest version.

Comment: @Steffen This problem is also happening on my Rackspace Ubuntu 16.04 server.

Comment: @RGuy not that it is likely this has anything to do with your issue but... slimgems has not been updated in nearly 10 years; rails 2.3 hit EOL 7 years ago and ruby 1.8.7 reached its EOL more than 6 years ago. It is time to upgrade everything